# не могу понять как работает область видимости во вложенных функциях

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, декоратор, scope

```
def second_outer(*dargs, **dkwargs):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            
            attempts = dkwargs['attempts']
            while attempts > 0: # ???
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as error:
                    print('Error', error)
                    attempts -= 1
        
        return inner
    return outer


@second_outer(attempts=5)
def div(a, b):
    return a / b


print(div(1, 0))
```

Не понимаю, почему while сразу не видит именованный аргумент, но видит ключ словаря

Comment: всё он видит...

Comment: разве? если убрать строку с созданием переменной attempts, то ничего while не видит

Comment: ну я запустил цикл `while dkwargs['attempts'] > 0`

Comment: так вопрос заключается в том, почему ключ словаря виден, а как заданное значение - нет. это понятно, что можно и другим способом достучаться до значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто проверим - а какие локальные переменные вообще видны внутри:

```py
def second_outer(*dargs, **dkwargs):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            
            print(locals())
            ...

@second_outer(attempts=5)
def div(a, b):
    return a / b

print(div(1, 0))
```

Вывод:

```
{'args': (1, 0), 'kwargs': {}, 'dkwargs': {'attempts': 5}, 'func': <function div at 0x7fd9a45a3550>}
```

Ну то есть нет внутри ваших функций никакой отдельной локальной переменной `attempts`. Эта "переменная" существует только в виде элемента словаря `dkwargs`. И это логично - в аргументах описания декоратора `second_outer` такой переменной нет, там есть только словарь `dkwargs`, внутри которого она и передаётся. И это правильно - мало ли что вы там снаружи захотите передать, вдруг вы захотите перекрыть какую-то уже существующую локальную переменную, например. Небезопасно это - создавать произвольные переменные просто потому, что функция вызвана с таким аргументом. А вот имя словаря жёстко прописано в заголовке функции, никаких проблем и неожиданностей это точно не вызовет.

Вывод: внутри функций существуют только те локальные переменные (да и глобальные тоже), которые были в явном виде где-то описаны. Параметры функции, задаваемые при вызове функции, передаются либо в виде явно описанных в описании функции аргументов, либо в виде словаря в виде описания `**kwargs` в заголовке функции. Никаких "секретных" или "скрытых" переменных внутри функции не может оказаться только потому, что вы их описали при вызове функции (а не в описании самой функции).

Comment: спасибо огромное за такое емкое обьяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `**kw` это словарь название указания и его значение. Если вы планируете обойтись без переменной создания `attempts` тогда в `second_outer` параметры   `*dargs, **dkwargs` надо заменить на `attemps` (вызов будет либо `second_outer(5)`, либо `second_outer(attemps=5)`), или на `*, attemps` (вызов будет только `second_outer(attemps=5)`). Если я не подробно объяснил прочитайте ответ от @CrazyElf.

Comment: спасибо огромное за обьяснение!